# fail to install package ‘RcppArmadillo’ on ubuntu 20.04 R version 4.1.3

Tags: r, ubuntu, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to install the 'forecast' package for my shiny server on ubuntu.
that process on my terminal is just getting stuck and once stopping the installation- it says:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
```

so i tried but failed to install 'RcppArmadillo' in two different ways:

**first way through R** (got stuck again):

`install.packages("RcppArmadillo")`

```
and again it get stuck:
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'   -I../inst/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'   -I../inst/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'   -I../inst/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-lENDSu/r-base-4.1.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
^Cmake: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: fastLm.o] Interrupt
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/shiny/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppArmadillo’
```

**second way:**
`$ sudo apt install r-cran-rcpparmadillo`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rcpparmadillo : Depends: r-api-3.5
                        Depends: r-cran-rcpp (>= 0.11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: r-cran-pkgkitten but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

any suggestions?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is (effectively) a FAQ as well. Your best bet is to look at the [README for Ubuntu at CRAN about 5k packages](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#get-5000-cran-packages) so that you can add the PPA.  After than, `sudo apt install r-cran-rcpparmadillo` will get you the current version.

Here is what I do in one of the Rocker Projects containers:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        software-properties-common \
        dirmngr \
        ed \
        less \
        locales \
        vim-tiny \
        wget \
        ca-certificates \
        && add-apt-repository --enable-source --yes "ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0" \
        && add-apt-repository --enable-source --yes "ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+"
```

You may or may not need to install to install `dirmngr` and `software-properties-common` so maybe try just

```
sudo add-apt-repository --enable-source --yes "ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0" 
sudo add-apt-repository --enable-source --yes "ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+"
```

and you do *not* need the first if you already get current R from CRAN, its the source repo for what is mirrored at CRAN.  But `c2d4u4.0+` is what you want for 5000+ binary CRAN packages for `focal`.

Comment: Did your short recommendation and worked like a charm! `sudo add-apt-repository --enable-source --yes "ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+"` and then: `sudo apt install r-cran-rcpparmadillo` thanks a lot! @Dirk

Comment: Great! It is a _marvellous_ I am using on several machines, via CI, ... and have for years.  Should be better known, so by all means spread the word too!